# @mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation not working in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic5

I try to use cordova-plugin-background-geolocation in Ionic 5 project, in foreground its working properly but in background it not working

```
ionic cordova plugin add "@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation": "^3.1.0"
npm install "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^5.28.0"
```

> Below code which are using

```
let config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
            desiredAccuracy: 0,
            stationaryRadius: 20,
            distanceFilter: 10,
            debug: false,
            interval: 1000
        };
        this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).then((location) => {
            // Run update inside of Angular's zone
            // Calling Service to save coordinates
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
        this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue,

IONIC INFO

sagarpatel@Sagars-MacBook-Air TripLogs % ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.4.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
@angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.2
native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/sagarpanchal/Library/Android/sdk)
ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
ios-sim           : 8.0.2
NodeJS            : v12.16.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm               : 6.14.4
OS                : macOS Big Sur
Thanks.